# How to take the meaning of "inherited onwards"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> We people are the original people, black hair, yellow skin, inherited
> onwards.

1. Is "inherited onwards" the modifier of "yellow skin" or the predicate complement of "we people"?
2. How to take the meaning of "onwards"?

Comment: I can't figure out a logical meaning for it as a native speaker. Its tone is decidedly poetic for several reasons, including the ellipsis that makes it hard to assign the modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important context: this appears to be a quotation from Xi Jinping.

> “Egypt is a bit more ancient,” Xi admitted. “But the only continuous civilization to continue onwards is China.”
> “We people are the original people, black hair, yellow skin, inherited onwards,” Xi laughed.

Xi is not a native speaker of English, and in this case he has produced some non-natively phrased sentences.

From context, I suspect he is saying this, but I have no proof:

> Egypt is an older civilisation than China. But the Egyptian civilisation has less continuity with its past than the Chinese civilisation. We Chinese people are the same Chinese people that existed in ancient times; we have the same black hair and yellow skin, inherited from thousands of years ago.